# Copy UFW rules between servers

Tags: firewall, ufw

I'm doing a hardware refresh on a my Colo, I just need to copy my UFW rules from my old server to my new server. I dont seem to be able to get them copy all the active rules from my old server to my new one.

How do I copy my active UFW rules between servers?

Comment: I found it in /lib/ufw/user.rules and /lib/ufw/user6.rules. I copy that between server, deactivate and reactive ufw and the rules applied.

Comment: Squidly you can answer and accept your own answer to your question.  It may help others who run into a similar problem as they may skip this question if they see it has 0 replies and doesn't have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found the rules in `/etc/ufw/user.rules` and for ipv6 you can find the rules in `/etc/ufw/user6.rules`.

If you copy those files between the servers, disable and then re-enable ufw.

Comment: I couldn't find the rules in /lib/ufw on a recent installation of UFW. /etc/ufw seems to be the right place,

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. The rules are in /etc/ufw/[after.init, before.init, ufw.conf, user.rules and so on]

Comment: where are comments kept?

Comment: @PawelCioch in user.rules and user6.rules as [`comment=hex-string`](https://serverfault.com/a/1101891/270385).

Answer (score 10):

User configurations for UFW should be in `/etc/ufw`. You are not supposed to modify files in `/lib` nor `/usr/lib` nor any other similar locations, because your modifications might get overwritten by the vendor's default version after the packages upgraded.

From Ubuntu 16.04:

`ls /etc/ufw`

> after6.rules  applications.d  before.rules  **user6.rules**
>   after.init    before6.rules   sysctl.conf   **user.rules**
>   after.rules   before.init     ufw.conf

Comment: Valid for Devuan 2.0 too

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be:

Save current config with:

`iptables-save >/to/some/filename`

Then restore it with:

`iptables-restore </to/some/filename`

Comment: This is a bad approach since iptables-save would spit out all other rules not relevant to UFW rules (example: docker puts its stuff into iptables, fail2ban, custom rules like traffic shaping etc.)  Much better approach would be to get "UFW only" rules from the /etc/ufw/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

Those /lib/ufw/user.rules /lib/ufw/user6.rules are just symlinks to /etc/ufw/user...

Copy those files from and to /etc/ufw directory

Comment: there are no symlinks in /bin/ufw/ in my recent ufw installation